# Find the rows for customers that joined during a specific time period in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the 2 following tables:

`customer_transaction`

```
 customer_id| event_name  | event_date

1          | joined_rewards|2019-07-10

12         | joined_rewards|2018-07-10

17         | joined_rewards|2009-07-10
```

`visit`

```
 customer_id| visit_start| visit_end|visit_type 

1          | 2019-07-09|2019-07-11| IP

12         | 2018-06-11|2018-07-12| IP

17         | 2009-07-08|2009-07-10| EP
```

I want to know all the customers in the `customer_transaction` table that joined the rewards program between their `visits` of visit_type = IP. So for all the visit_types = IP, I want to know the customers who joined the rewards program during the frame of their visit period.

In this example, my new table would have customer ids 1 and 12.

I tried

````
SELECT DISTINCT customer_id, event_date
INTO visit_rewards
FROM customer_transaction
WHERE event_date BETWEEN (Select customer_id, visit_start, visit_end from visit)```
````

Comment: Have a look at between, it expects two values. You're almost there.

Answer (score 1):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b61ee58272adf0426e52a5cc0c5c6639)

```
SELECT 
    v.customer_id
FROM
    visit v
JOIN customer_transaction ct 
ON ct.event_date BETWEEN v.visit_start AND v.visit_end
    AND v.visit_type = 'IP'
```

Comment: Did this help? Please do not forget to upvote ALL helpful answers (which honors the work and time the repliers invested into your question) and accept the best fitting answer (to close the question). Otherwise please tell us, what to change.

Answer (score 0):

If there can be multiple rows in the visits table (as suggested by the name), I would suggest `exists`:

```
select ct.*
from customer_transaction ct
where ct.event_name = 'joined_rewards' and
      exists (select 1
              from visits v
              where v.customer_id = ct.customer_id and
                    v.visit_start <= ct.event_date and
                    v.visit_end >= ct.event_date and
                    v.visit_type = 'IP'
             );
```